# Calling FancyBox inside getJSON and setInterval

Tags: jquery, fancybox, setinterval, getjson, fancybox-2

I am trying to use getJSON method to get the status-code and if the status code is > 0, I want to show a fancybox window.

I want this process to be executed every 5 seconds ( using setInterval function). The script executes without any error. Alerts as shown below is shown but not the fancybox DIV.

When status is > 0 show the fancybox popup and if not, don't show it.

Please correct me where I am doing wrong.

Here is the HTML code.

```
<div style="display:none">
   <div id="myModal">
     <h1>Conversion in Progress</h1>
   </div> 
</div>
```

Here is the jQuery code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {           

    function myplugin() {             
        $.getJSON("get-status.php", function (data) {                        
              $.each(data, function (key, status) {   
                   if(status > 0) {
                      alert("Bad Status");         // Works;
                      $("#myModal").fancybox();
                   }else{
                      alert("Good Status");        // Works;
                      $.fancybox.close();
                   }
               });       
        });  
     };

     $(function() {
          setInterval(function() { myplugin() }, 5000);
     });

});';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing fancybox but not actually triggering it.

Try adding `$("#myModal").fancybox().click();`

Comment: Wonderful. I know it would be something trivial. You made it. Thanks.